# Linear autonomous dynamical systems and the definition of Linearly independent vector functions

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I hope some of you will find some time to answer my following query, which has arisen in my math studies as an econ undergraduate:

I know that, given a dynamical system of the type $\vec{x}'=A\vec{x}$, with $x$ being a vector function of time $t$ and $A$ being an n-dimensional square matrix, the motion law can be rephrased as the kernel of a linear operator $\vec{x}'-A\vec{x}$, so any linear combination of any two solutions is itself a solution to the dynamical system. I also know that, in light of the Cauchy existence-uniqueness theorem, every Initial Value Problem with $\vec{x}(t_0)=\vec{x}_0$ has a solution. Now from these results, as far as I was able to grasp, my lecture notes infer that the set of the images of all particular solutions to the system evaluated at any $t_0$ must be $\mathbb R^n$, and hence, all solutions must be spanned by an $n$-dimensional basis of L.I. fundamental ones. Up until this point, I'm aboard.

What puzzles me is the subsequent definition of linear independence of vector functions: it states that a set of vector functions is said to be linearly independent if and only if their images are L.I. *at least at one* real number $t_0$. I would have expected that said functions be linearly independent if their image is linearly independent at *every* $t_0$! How is this definition consistent with the previous results, meaning how can the possibility that the n L.I. fundamental solutions be linearly dependent at some $t_0$ be reconciled be the fact that such a set is supposed to span $\mathbb R^n$ when evaluated at any arbitrary $t_0$? I'll provide you with an example to better outline my doubt (I know this example can't possibly apply to linear dynamical systems, and I apologize for that, but it is still relevant to the broader notion of Linear independence for functions):

$\varphi_1= \begin{pmatrix} \sin(t)\\ \cos(t)\end{pmatrix},$

$\varphi_2= \begin{pmatrix} \sin(t)\\ \sin(t)\end{pmatrix},$

are L.I., according to the definition I was given, because at $t=\pi/2$ for instance their images are $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, two l.i. vectors. If we assume them to be two particular solutions to a hypothetical dynamical system, they should span all possible solutions, so the general solution should be:

$φ=c_1φ_1+c_2φ_2$ for some $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R$

Then again, if we evaluate the two particular solutions at $t=0$, we get that their images are $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$(0,1), two linearly dependent vectors. Now, by the existence-uniqueness theorem we know that there should exist a solution $φ(t)$ such that $φ(0)=\begin{pmatrix} k\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ for every real k. However, $\begin{pmatrix} k\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ is in no way spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, either the two L.I. particular solutions do not span all possible solutions, or there is no solution to such an IVP, which either way contradicts some result I was presented with. How do I sort things out? What am I neglecting/misconceiving? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set of functions is linearly **dependent** if one of them is a linear combination of the rest, in the sense that
$$
f_k(t)=\sum_i f_i(t)
$$
for every $t$. The negation of that is that this is not the case at some $t$.

If your solutions are dependent at some $t_0$, they will be dependent for every $t$ automatically, by linearity.

If they are independent at some $t_0$, they will be independent for all $t$ since the Wronskian determinant is
$$
W(t)=W(t_0)e^{-\int Tr(A)\,dt}
$$
(Abel-Liouville formula). What this implies is that the two "solutions" that you propose cannot be solutions to any such linear systems.

Observe that the equivalence independent at a point $\equiv$ independent at every point is only true about solutions of some linear system, not for functions in general.